# Create a query that returns the top five highest results per each group

Tags: sql, sqlite, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to write a query that returns the top 5 customers who spent highest money in each state using SQLite and my code is not doing it. How can i make it work?

```
SELECT name, state, transact_amt,
FROM 
customers
JOIN 
transactions
ON customers.customer_id = transactions.customer_id
DENSE_RANK () OVER (
PARTITION BY state
ORDER BY transact_amt
)rn
SELECT name, state, transact_amt
WHERE rn <= 5;
```

Comment: I'd start with a good SQL tutorial to learn the language, because that has all sorts of syntax errors and looks like you just threw random snippets together in random order.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite+greatest-n-per-group